# Is it possible to call Angular 4 method based on url/route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am very new to Angular (4) and I would like to know if it is possible to call a method based on a specific url, similar to Ruby on Rails where routes are dispatch to controller actions.

For example, if I have the route http://example.com/#/home/success I would like to call the *home component's success method*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean statically, see:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Code sample:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home/:message', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }`
```

You can use `ActivatedRoute` to get the params.

Comment: what exactly do you mean my statically or dynamically?